# How to do loop all the metamask Accounts loop and display data from that address in React frontend + Dapp App JS

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, react, solidity-0.5.x

I want to Display data stored on the Ropsten Network in more then 2 metamask accounts.

I want to display the result on the Home page in the table form.

For that I need to loop through each accounts who store data and display.

Following is my code to getData function and I am showing on load( componentDidMount )

```
getData = async() => {
 const {accounts, contract} = this.state;
 const response = await 
 contract.methods.getData().call({from:accounts[0]});
}
```

I am using web3 1.0.0-beta.37 and React JS is on frontend.

I have read somewhere that when we do web3.eth.accounts it will silently take accounts[0]. is it correct?

Comment: Im not sure that this is possible, metamask has only one active account at time. There is a trick with some limitations, if you use the same MNEMONIC, which you used in metamask to generate your new accounts, then you can generate the same accounts one by one and get their data